# PHP date format: the % sign

Tags: php, date

I often see two ways of formatting the format string: `%d-%m-%Y` and without the `%`, `d-m-Y`. Can someone explain what is the difference and which one should we use in what case?

Comment: Depends which method you are using, make sure to check the docs first.  PHP is known for being very inconsistent when it comes to methods sharing formats.  `date()` uses `d-m-Y`, but `DateInterval::format()` uses `%d-%m-%Y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The percent sign (`%`) is used to format a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). With functions such as [`date()`](http://php.net/date), you use `d-m-Y`, but when formatting a DateInterval, each  format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (`%`) -- so you'll need `%d-%m-%Y` instead.

They're entirely different and have different use-cases. What *you should use* depends somewhat on details of what you're trying to do and what method you're using.

Comment: actually the confusion comes from this http://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type I have no idea how this is related to DateInterval and use % ..